# Drupal 7: giving "Find Content" access to particular role

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-modules, drupal-7, roles

I created "content admin" role for client. I won't give administrator account to client.

I need to give access to Find Content page to client, so they can list/edit any page. but I dont have permission setting for this page :/

How do I give access to "Find Content" page for particular role.

Find Content's url is http://test.com/admin/content

Appreciate helps!! Thanks a lot!

---

**UPDATE:**

sorted with 
permission setting for **Access the content overview page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SORTED!**

sorted with permission setting for Access the content overview page